# Jquery - turn onclick on and off

Tags: jquery

i have a table where all the tds have an onlick event, the thing is i want to turn them off to avoid multiple clicks on the same td, but later on the script i want to turn them on again

I have something like this:

```
$(tdidhere).prop("onclick",false);
$(tdidhere).prop("onclick",true);
```

The thing is the onclick false works fine, but onclick true wont give the onclick event back

Comment: The simplest thing would be to have a global flag and set that to true/false, and have `if (!flag) return;` inside the click handlers.

Comment: @Archer great minds... ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My Mother taught me that fools seldom differ ;)

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to hold a property governing whether or not the `click` event can be handled for that element. Something like this;

```
$('#myTd').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('click-blocked')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
       $(this).data('click-blocked', true);

       // your click logic

       $(this).data('click-blocked', false);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/PkvXR/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting it to `true` won't work. You'll need to re-assign the original event handler function.

To deactivate:

```
// backup the original event handler
$(tdidhere).prop("onclick_backup", $(tdidhere).prop("onclick"));
$(tdidhere).prop("onclick",false);
```

To reactivate:

```
// restore the original event handler
$(tdidhere).prop("onclick", $(tdidhere).prop("onclick_backup"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$("id").bind('click',function(){...})` and `$("id").unbind('click')`
[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)